# How to find out what version of webdeploy/msdeploy is currently installed?

Tags: powershell, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm looking for something like a Powershell script to check if msdeploy is installed and if it is, what version

I've considered checking "c:\Program Files\IIS" and checking for MSDeploy installations there, but is this always guaranteed to be the install location?

I need this to work on any given server machine

Comment: `msdeploy | find "Version"`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson this would only work if it is set up in the PATH variables

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When `msdeploy` is installed (no matter where in the file system), it will add its install path to the registry at;

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\<version>\InstallPath
```

and its version information to;

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\<version>\Version
```

...where `<version>` is currently 1, 2 or 3 depending on the WebDeploy version you have installed.

Comment: Note that `InstallPath` and `Version` are not subkeys, but rather they are values on the `<version>` key. (Important if you're looking at this programmatically.)

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what you consider "version". By the folder name "c:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3", the version is 3, but if you run msdeploy.exe, the version is 7.X

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did in my PowerShell script:

```
$WebDeployInstalled = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | ? {$_.Name -like '*Microsoft Web Deploy*'}
if ($WebDeployInstalled -eq $null)
{
    $msg = "Microsoft Web Deploy is not found on this machine."
    Write-host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White $msg
    return
}
else
{
    $MSDeployPath = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\*" | Select-Object InstallPath
    $MSDeployPath = $MSDeployPath.InstallPath
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following PowerShell snippet:

```
$installPath = $env:msdeployinstallpath
if(!$installPath){
    $keysToCheck = @('hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3','hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\2','hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\1')
    foreach($keyToCheck in $keysToCheck) {
        if(Test-Path $keyToCheck){
            $installPath = (Get-itemproperty $keyToCheck -Name InstallPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -ExpandProperty InstallPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        }
        if($installPath) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you wrap it into script block then you can call it in remote session.